# Making an XP based computer apply policy template to only certain users

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, templates, local

I have a device running Windows XP that is not on a domain. I want to lock the non-admin user down.

I got the SteadyState .adm templates files for lock down (using SteadyState caused problems with my logon scripts).

The problem is, that all the restrictions are for all users, so I can lock even the admin out of everything.

Can anyone think of a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System-wide policies in ADM templates are just that...system wide.  Assuming the settings they're configuring are true "*policies*" and not just "*preferences*", all that happens is registry values get written to various places within **HKLM\Software\Policies**.  And while you might think you could just move those registry settings to HKCU for the user in question, it probably won't work since the system components that are reading those registry keys won't actually know to look there.

Unfortunately, I think you're out of luck.